# Writing a Function Using pandas and Returning Data in Required Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, highcharts

I have this `total_of_each_error` data frame:

```
    month        name       errors     count
0   January     ABCD        Big         1
1   January     ABCD      Monitoring    3
2   January     WORLD     Small         1
3   January     Channel    Big          2
4   January     Channel   Small         1
5   January     Channel  Monitoring     1
6   January     AVR      Monitoring     1
7   March       WORLD     Monitoring    2
8   April       Migration    Big        1
9   April       Migration Monitoring    2
10  May         P&G       Small         1
11  May         P&G       Monitoring    1
12  May         ABCD      Monitoring    1
13  May         WORLD    Improvement    1
14  June        P&G      Monitoring     1
15  June        ABCD         Small      1
16  June        ABCD     Monitoring     1
```

I have written this function:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

def get_chartdata(df):
    months = df['month'].unique().tolist()
    no_of_errors = df['errors'].unique().tolist()
    name = df['name'].unique().tolist()
    cross_df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(months, name, no_of_errors)), columns=['month','name','errors'])
    merged_df = pd.merge(total_of_each_error,cross_df,how='outer', left_on=['month','name','errors'], 
         right_on=['month','name','errors']).drop_duplicates().fillna(0)            

    pivot_df = merged_df.pivot_table(columns='month', index=['name','errors'], values='count', fill_value=0).reset_index() 
    data = {}
    for index, row in pivot_df.iterrows():
        if (row['name']) not in data.keys():
            data[row['name']] = []
        data[row['name']].append({'name':row.values[1:2].tolist() , 'data': row.values[2:].tolist()})


    x_axis = {}
    for i in pivot_df['name'].unique():
        df1 = pivot_df[pivot_df['name'] == i]
        x_axisData = pivot_df.columns[2:].unique()
        x_axis[i] = {'categories': x_axisData.tolist()}    
    return data, x_axis
```

`print(get_chartdata(total_of_each_error))` prints the following:

```
({'P&G': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}, {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]}, {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
  'ABCD': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 3, 1, 0, 1]}, {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
  'WORLD': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 2, 0]}, {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}],
  'Migration': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
  'Channel': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
  'AVR': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]},
 {'P&G': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']}, 'ABCD': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
  'WORLD': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
  'Migration': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
  'Channel': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
  'AVR': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']}})
```

I am getting `categories` as `['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']`, but I want it to be `['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']`, and the `data` should also match with this order.

I am creating charts using Highcharts and passing the above data to Django template. An example chart is at https://jsfiddle.net/nbtejvau/9/

**Edit**: Added Highcharts tag.

Expected output:

```
data = {'WORLD': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
                'series': [{
                    'name': 'Big',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Bigs in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Small',
                    'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Smalls in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Monitoring',
                    'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Monitorings in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Improvement',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  # Number of Improvements in those months
                    }]
                },
        'P&G': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
                'series': [{
                    'name': 'Big',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Small',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Monitoring',
                    'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Improvement',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                    }]
                }      

    }
```

Similar output expected for the remaining in `total_of_each_error['name']`

Comment: Hi Diana, welcome to SO. Your question and code are too big and its not easy to understand where you want to get at. Please pose an expected output for the input your provided (the data frame)

Comment: Hi RafaelC, sorry, just added my expected output. Hope it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Added swapping logic into your final dataset,

```
data = {'P&G': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
                {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]},
                {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]},
                {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
        'ABCD': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
                 {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]},
                 {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 3, 1, 0, 1]},
                 {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
        'WORLD': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
                  {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
                  {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 2, 0]},
                  {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}],
        'Migration': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
                      {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
                      {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
                      {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
        'Channel': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]},
                    {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
                    {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
                    {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
        'AVR': [{'name': ['Big'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
                {'name': ['Small'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
                {'name': ['Monitoring'], 'data': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
                {'name': ['Improvement'], 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}

x_axis = {'P&G': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
          'ABCD': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
          'WORLD': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
          'Migration': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
          'Channel': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']},
          'AVR': {'categories': ['April', 'January', 'June', 'March', 'May']}}

target_month_order = ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']

final_data = dict()
for name in x_axis.keys():
    # Modifying data1
    final_data[name] = dict()
    final_data[name]['categories'] = target_month_order
    # Modifying data2
    final_data[name]['series'] = list()
    print('Swapping - ', name)
    actual_month_order = x_axis[name]['categories']
    swap_index = [actual_month_order.index(month) for month in target_month_order]
    _tmp = data[name]
    for _val in _tmp:
        _new_list = []
        for swap_idx in swap_index:
            _new_list.append(_val['data'][swap_idx])
        # print(list(zip(actual_month_order, _val['data'])))
        # print(list(zip(target_month_order, _new_list)))
        final_data[name]['series'].append({'name': _val['name'], 'data': _new_list})
        print('--')
    # print(swap_index)
    # print(final_data[name]['series'])

print(' *-*' * 20)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(final_data)
```

Output

```
 *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-* *-*
{'ABCD': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
          'series': [{'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Big']},
                     {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'name': ['Small']},
                     {'data': [3, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'name': ['Monitoring']},
                     {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Improvement']}]},
 'AVR': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
         'series': [{'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Big']},
                    {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Small']},
                    {'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Monitoring']},
                    {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Improvement']}]},
 'Channel': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
             'series': [{'data': [2, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Big']},
                        {'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Small']},
                        {'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Monitoring']},
                        {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Improvement']}]},
 'Migration': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
               'series': [{'data': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 'name': ['Big']},
                          {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Small']},
                          {'data': [0, 0, 2, 0, 0], 'name': ['Monitoring']},
                          {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Improvement']}]},
 'P&G': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
         'series': [{'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Big']},
                    {'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'name': ['Small']},
                    {'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'name': ['Monitoring']},
                    {'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Improvement']}]},
 'WORLD': {'categories': ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
           'series': [{'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Big']},
                      {'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Small']},
                      {'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['Monitoring']},
                      {'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'name': ['Improvement']}]}}
```